# Gsub to get part matched strings in R regular expression?

Tags: regex, r

```
gsub('[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]{5})','\\1','htf84756.iuy')
[1] "84756.iuy"
```

I want to get 84756,how can i do?

Comment: That regular expression works as is using `strapplyc` in the gsubfn package: `library(gsubfn); strapplyc('htf84756.iuy', '[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]{5})', simplify = TRUE)` .   See http://gsubfn.googlecode.com .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
R> gsub('[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]{5}).*','\\1','htf84756.iuy')
[1] "84756"
R>
```

You need the added `.*` at the end of the "greedy" regexp to terminate it after the 5 digits.

Comment: +1 But perhaps not so much *terminate* it as *match* the remainder of the string, so that it's not just left in place by the call to `gsub()`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `gregexpr()` with `regmatches()` has the advantage of only requiring that your pattern match the bit that you actually want to extract:

```
string <- 'htf84756.iuy'
pat <- "(\\d){5}"

regmatches(string, gregexpr(pat, string))[[1]]
# [1] "84756"
```

(In practice, these functions are more useful when a supplied string might contain more than one substring matching `pat`.)

Answer (score 2):

This could work as well (like Dirk's answer better) based on what to add to yours:

```
gsub('[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]{5})\\.([a-zA-Z])+','\\1','htf84756.iuy')
```

If you just want the numeric string this may be helpful as well:

```
gsub('[^0-9]','','htf84756.iuy')
```

Comment: Note that the "." only matches a "." by chance and if you really want to specify an actual period you need to escape it.  It also seems you don't need to make the last section of your first regex a marked subexpression since you aren't grabbing anything from it.  And in your second one you don't need to replace with \\1 since there is nothing in your expression that is a subexpression so it does the same thing as replacing with "".

Comment: @Dason thanks for the suggestions.  I made the changes in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

With `stringr`, you can use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("htf84756.iuy", "[0-9]+")
```