# Gsub puzzle in R:the match pattern

Tags: r

```
gsub("([a-z]+)([0-9]+)","\\2","ytu678yu")
[1] "678yu"
gsub("([a-z]+)([0-9]+)(.*)","\\2","ytu678yu")
[1] "678"
```

I wonder why  `gsub("([a-z]+)([0-9]+)","\\2","ytu678yu")`  can not get `678`?

Comment: Should this have been asked in a comment to your earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966207/gsub-to-get-part-matched-strings-in-r-regular-expression)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the pattern matches "ytu678" and then this is replaced by "\2" ie "678", so finally you get "678yu".

In the second case, the pattern matches "ytu678yu" and then this is replaced by "\2" ie "678", so finally you get "678".

Try this:

```
> gsub("([a-z]+)([0-9]+)","","ytu678yu")
[1] "yu"
> gsub("([a-z]+)([0-9]+)(.*)","","ytu678yu")
[1] ""
```

Comment: As another example, if the OP just wants the numbers from the string, `gsub("[a-z]+","","ytu678yu")`. +1